# $A\subset J_n$, $f:A\to J_n$ bijection implies $A=J_n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Although it seems obvious, I'm having trouble to prove this one:

> If $J_n=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and $A\subset J_n$ with $A$ equipotent to $J_n$, then $A=J_n$. (Here "equipotent" means that exists a bijection $f:J_n\to A$).

Comment: If there exists a bijection then the dimension of each set must be the same.

Comment: Isn't this just (a version of) the pigeonhole principle in disguise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a rather basic result, I think any proof will be very sensitive to the chosen axioms and definitions (for example, you may fall in circular reasoning if you use the pigeon hole principle or other similar result, depending on how the theory was developed). But consider the following:

> If $A\neq J_n$, then there is no bijection $J_n\to A$

We proceede by induction on $n$. The case $n=0$ is trivial. For the induction step, if the assertion is false for $n+1$, then there exists a bijection $f:J_{n+1}\to B$, where $B$ is a proper subset of $J_{n+1}$. Now we have two cases:

If $n+1\not\in B$, then $B\subset J_n$ and $f|_{J_n}$ is a surjection of $J_n$ onto the proper subset $B\setminus \{f(n+1)\}$ of $J_n$, which contradicts the induction hypothesis.

If $n+1\in B$, then $n+1=f(k)$, for some $k\leq n+1$. Consider now the function $g$ definied on $J_n$ by
$$g(i)=\begin{cases} f(i) & \mbox{for all } i\neq k, i<n+1\\
f(n+1) & \mbox{if } i=k<n+1\end{cases}.$$
Then $g$ is a bijection onto $B\setminus\{n+1\}$, a proper subset of $J_n$, a contradiction again.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: J_n \to A$ be a bijective function. This means that $\forall j\in J_n, \exists! a \in A: f(j)=a$, and $f^{-1}(a) = j$. Suppose that $A \neq J_n$. This means that there exists $j'\in J_n: \forall a\in A, f(j')\neq a$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry @VladimirVargas, I didn't get it...

Ok, suppose that $A\neq J_n$. Since $A\subset J_n$, this means that exists $j'\in J_n$ such that $j'\notin A$. How exactly does this implies your "This means that exists $j'\in J_n:\nexists a\in A$ such that $f(j')=a$"?

Comment: @AndersonFelipeViveiros I wrote it differently to be clearer

Comment: @AndersonFelipeViveiros this is just a way of writing the definition. Two sets have the same cardinality if and only if there exists a bijection.

Comment: Yes, sure. Two sets have the same cardinality if and only if exists a bijection between them. But, even with your edit, I still can't see how "$\exists j'\in J_n\,|\, j'\notin A$" implies that what you have written... I completely agree that your claim "kills" the problem, but didn't see how this implication happens...

Comment: Sorry, @VladimirVargas... :(

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A\neq J_n$. Since $A\subset J_n$, this means that exists $j\in J_n$ such that $j\notin A$. Therefore, $\forall a \in A$, $a\neq j$. This, together with the fact that every $a\in A$ is so that $a\in J_n$, implies that $A\subset J_n\backslash \{j\}$. So, denoting by $i_A:A\to J_n\backslash \{j\}$ the inclusion, we have a injective map
$$i_A\circ f:J_n\to J_n\backslash\{j\}.$$ 
Considering that exists a bijection between $J_n\backslash\{j\}$ and $J_{n-1}$, say $g:J_n\backslash\{j\}\to J_{n-1}$, we would have a injection
$$h=g\circ i_A\circ f:J_n\to J_{n-1},$$
which contradicts the pigeonhole principle.

Edit: As $g:J_n\backslash\{j\}\to J_{n-1}$ we can take
$$g(k)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} k,& \text{ if $k<j$}\\
k-1, & \text{ if $k>j$}.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: looks quite good.